# Создание бд и таблицы

Tags: c#, mono, mysql

Каким образом можно проверить существует ли бд с определенным именем или нет и если её нет то создать её, а так же таблицу в ней?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну про существование БД можно залезть в БД

**information_schema**

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `TABLES` where TABLE_SCHEMA='namedatabase'
```

Если выборка пройдет и выберет название БД то значит БД есть, если не выберет, то нет.

Так же и таблицы можно проверить но уже по полю

```
   SELECT * 
    FROM  `TABLES` where TABLE_NAME='nametable'
```

Comment: Спасибо!

только `TABLES` без кавычек, поправьте пожалуйста.

А чтобы проверить нашлась информация или нет, надо через ExecuteNonQuery выполнять ?

Comment: На самом деле как раз таки с кавычками, при правильном синтаксисе.
А можно и без них, ошибки тут нет.

>А чтобы проверить нашлась информация или нет, 
>надо через ExecuteNonQuery выполнять 

Какая информация? Вопрос был про БД и Таблицы, остальное в другом вопросе, либо описать подробнее что нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Create Table If Not Exists

Comment: а база данных?

Comment: наверно надо писать хранимую процедуру, которая проверит бд запросом к information_schema, а потом создаст, если нету

Comment: >Create Table If Not Exists


Это создание если нет, а проверить на существование БД и таблицы в ней, все-таки лучше лезть в **information_schema**